# TimezonePicker with jquery and primefaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces

i need a timezone Picker component to use in my GUI , i haven't found a ready to use component in Primefaces , sadly .
can you point me to interresting components i can use ?

Comment: how about a simple drop down? populated with the help of `TimeZone` class? like (`TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`) , you can also look at this : http://timezonepicker.com/